# Providing sessions when testing middleware in Express

Tags: node.js, express, supertest, express-session, nock

I am attempting to test middleware functions in my Express application using supertest and nock, but am having issues where the routes I have setup are checked by an earlier piece of middleware to ensure a session property exists on the incoming `req` object.

I need to somehow mock out the session object prior to running the tests, but am unsure how to approach this. First let me share some code:

**router.js**

```
app.use('/api', helpers.hasAccessToken, require('./routes.js'));
```

**routes.js**

```
router.route('/*')
  .get(routesController.fetch)
```

**helpers.js**

```
module.exports.hasAccessToken = function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.accessToken){
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('LOGIN_SESSION_ENDED');
  }
};
```

**routesController.js**

```
module.exports.fetch = function(req, res) {
  var options = helpers.buildAPIRequestOptions(req);
  request(options, function(err, response, body){
    res.status(response.statusCode).send(body);
  });
};
```

**routesController.spec.js**

```
var app = require('./index.js'),
  request = require('supertest')(app),
  expect = require('chai').expect,
  nock = require('nock');


describe('GET requests', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    nock('https://10.105.195.12:8243')
      .get('/v1/schemes')
      .reply(200, {foo:'bar'});
  });
  it('should return a 200 HTTP status code', function(done){
    request
      .get('/api/schemes')
      .end(function(err, res){
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

My test fails as the value for `res.status` is 401. I am using express-session, but I wondered if there was some way I could get at the `req.session` object in my test suite and set the value of the accessToken property prior to running any of the tests.

Can anyone offer any advice\thoughts please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Lets create some stub for `req.session` object with value that is under our control.

```
var app = require('./index.js'),
  request = require('supertest'), // no longer app here as we want to call parentApp
  expect = require('chai').expect,
  nock = require('nock');

describe('GET requests', function(){
  var parentApp;

  beforeEach(function(){
    parentApp = express();
    parentApp.use(function(req, res, next) { // lets stub session middleware
      req.session = {};
      next();
    })
    parentApp.get('/api', function(req, res, next) {
      req.session.accessToken = true;  // and provide some accessToken value
      next();
    })
    parentApp.use(app);
    nock('https://10.105.195.12:8243')
      .get('/v1/schemes')
      .reply(200, {foo:'bar'});
  });

  it('should return a 200 HTTP status code', function(done){
    request(parentApp) // we are testing now app through parentApp and stubbed middleware
      .get('/api/schemes')
      .end(function(err, res){
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```